# Hadoop Hive web interface options

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've been experimenting with Hive for some data mining activities and would like to make it easily available to less command line orientated colleagues.

Hive does now ship with a web interface (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/HiveWebInterface) but it's very basic at this stage.

My question is does a visually polished and fully featured interface (either desktop or preferably web based) to Hive exist yet? Are their any open source efforts outside the Hive project working on this?

Comment: To my knowledge none yet. But it might be best to look at the Cloudera forums and ask around. I have not looked at Cloudera for a couple of months.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now with new version of Cloudera's Hadoop Distribution comes HUE (Hadoop User Experience) with plugin called Beeswax, which most likely all you would need.

It's pretty tricky to configure, but one you get over it, it provides something like phpmyadmin interface, but is much nicer and easier. It supports writing queries, importing data, storing results, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That looks fantastic. Now to find the time to actually get it up and running.

Comment: Here's a link to a blog post about Hue and Beeswax: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/07/whats-new-in-cdh3b2-hue/

Comment: Here is a link to the Hue website which contains screenshots: http://cloudera.github.com/hue

Answer (score 2):

**Web based opensource GUI for Hive**

HWI - Shipped in Hive. with basic features.

Hue - Nice query editor with autocompletion. Support parameterized query. Latest version includes basic visualization of query result. Includes many other useful tools like managing HDFS, JobFlows, etc. Thus, heavy and little bit tricky to install and configure.

[Zeppelin](http://zeppelin-project.org) - Only includes Hive tool compare to Hue. Support query template. Pluggable visualization architecture and it's online archive, so easily create custom visualization and share it. Lightweight and easier to install than Hue while it does not include any feature for non-hive related things.

**Other alternatives**

Excel - Microsoft Excel is capable of making hive query and fetch data from hive. http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.1/bk_dataintegration/content/ch_using-hive-2.html has guide for doing it.

Commercial BI tool - Commercial BI tool like Tableau, Datameer, Karmasphere support connection to Hadoop or Hive. They have nice dashboards, charts. All they offer trial/community/personal edition.

Answer (score 0):

HUE is usefull and good but you should also try "Karmasphere Analyst Free/community Edition". It is very easy to use and well documented. Free version is very capable. It is not web based but it has different OS support (windows,linux...etc). YOu can check the GUI from documents to see how it looks.